# Know the name of the selected object at runtime

Tags: json, three.js

Sorry my english :  I loaded several objects. Json and I select them using the Ray and intersected doing that they change color. But I want to know which object loaded being selected at runtime. currently and using this code below and the output is: [object Object] 
$ var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( scene.children );

```
            if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

                if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].object ) {


                    var aux = intersects[ 0 ].object;

                    if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );


                    INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;

                    INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.emissive.getHex();
                    INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex( 0xffff00 );


                        console.debug("name:,"+aux);

                }

            } else {

                if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );

                INTERSECTED = null;


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a unique `id` to each mesh when you create it.

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.id = some_unique_id;
scene.add( mesh );
```

And then in your intersects logic:

```
if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

    alert( intersects[0].object.id );

}
```

Comment: unfortunately is not working with this code.
When I use the command some_unique_id the 3D model is not loaded in the browser.

Comment: No, no. You have to put something in reasonable for some_unique_id. Examples are mesh.id = 2, or mesh.id = j were j is a variable, or mesh.id = "Paula".